# confirm dialog fired three times with turbolinks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have this JS on my app

```
$(document).on('page:before-change', function(){
  if($('.chat-text-field').val())
    return confirm("Your message hasn't been sent yet. Do you still want to leave?");
});
```

turns out that this message is beign fired 3 times. I'm already using jquery.turbolinks gem. Is there something else missing?